# Difference between cv2.findNonZero and Numpy.NonZero

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Silly question here.

I want to find the locations of the pixels from some black and white images and found this two functions from Numpy library and OpenCV.

The example I found on the internet (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html):

```
    mask = np.zeros(imgray.shape,np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
    pixelpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))
    pixelpointsCV2 = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
```

Which states

> Numpy gives coordinates in **(row, column)** format, while OpenCV gives coordinates in **(x,y)** format. So basically the answers will be interchanged. Note that, row = x and column = y.

Based on my understanding of english, isn't their explanation wrong? Shouldn't it be:

> Numpy gives coordinates in (row, column) format, while OpenCV gives coordinates in **(y,x)** or **(column, row)** format.

My questions are:

1. Does numpy return **(row,col)**/**(x,y)** and OpenCV **(y,x)** where row=x, col=y? Although IMHO it should be row=y, col=x?
2. Which one is more computation efficient? In terms of time & resources.

Maybe I am not getting this simple thing right due to not being a non-native English speaker.

Comment: I think that the wrong part is _Note that, row = x and column = y_, which should be: _Note that, **row = y** and **column = x**_. So 1) numpy returns (row, col) = (y, x), and OpenCV returns (x,y) = (col, row). 2) Just run a few tests, but I don't think there will be any significant difference. Since you're working in python, I'd use python stuff (numpy)

Comment: @Miki I ran a few tests and indeed OpenCV returns (x,y) = (col,row). If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an error in the documentation:

> Numpy gives coordinates in (row, column) format, while OpenCV gives coordinates in (x,y) format. So basically the answers will be interchanged. <s>Note that, row = x and column = y.</s> **Note that, row = y and column = x.**

So, regarding your questions:

1. numpy returns `(row,col) = (y,x)`, and OpenCV returns `(x,y) = (col,row)`
2. You need to scan the whole matrix and retrieve some points. I don't think there will be any significant difference in performance (*should be tested!*).

   <s>Since you're using Python, probably it's better to use Python facilities, e.g. numpy.</s>

Runtime test comparing these two versions -

```
In [86]: mask = (np.random.rand(128,128)>0.5).astype(np.uint8)

In [87]: %timeit cv2.findNonZero(mask)
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.4 µs per loop

In [88]: %timeit np.nonzero(mask)
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop

In [89]: mask = (np.random.rand(512,512)>0.5).astype(np.uint8)

In [90]: %timeit cv2.findNonZero(mask)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop

In [91]: %timeit np.nonzero(mask)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.8 ms per loop

In [92]: mask = (np.random.rand(1024,1024)>0.5).astype(np.uint8)

In [93]: %timeit cv2.findNonZero(mask)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.75 ms per loop

In [94]: %timeit np.nonzero(mask)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
```

Thus, it seems using OpenCV results in something around `3x` speedup over the NumPy counterpart across varying datasizes.

Comment: On performance, `cv2` seems to be  around `3x` better across varying datasizes.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. If you have a small benchmark you can add to the answer (and I'll make it a "Community answer") ;D

Comment: See if the edits seem consistent  with your thoughts. Feel free to edit further if needed. Also, I think you should keep as it as a personal post :)

Comment: You answered half of the question. Thanks ;D

Comment: That's just a tiny portion of timings with just some numbers! :)

Comment: great answer. it would be better if that page were corrected because I've noticed there a lot of people who didn't notice the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some debugging, found an equivalent implementation between cv2 and NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

mask = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,1,1]])

coords = cv2.findNonZero(mask)

coords_numpy = np.argwhere(mask)
coords_numpy[:, [0, 1]] = coords_numpy[:, [1, 0]]
coords_numpy = np.expand_dims(coords_numpy, axis=1)
```